# How to optimise this cosine similarity loop and function in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to find cosine similarities between two lists of different sizes. I have this code but it is running for a long time. The first list has 40 000 words and the second list has 400 words. Is it possible to speed this up?

I have been trying different approaches instead of using vectorizer but none of the other approaches were as correct in terms of similarity scores, so if possible if I can stick to this approach would be great, otherwise other suggestions are welcome too.

I took a part of the code below from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897593/how-to-compute-the-similarity-between-two-text-documents).

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')

def cosine_simimlarity(w1, w2):
    tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform([w1, w2])
    return ((tfidf * tfidf.T).A)[0, 1]

lst1 = ['car', 'apple', 'apple pie', 'sky', 'flower']
lst2 = ['car bmw', 'fruit', 'apple orange', 'tree', 'flower apple']
dict_ = {}

for w1 in lst1:
        for w2 in lst2:
            dict_[(w1, w2)] = cosine_simimlarity(w1, w2)

print(dict_)
```

Comment: I don't think this code is doing what you want it to be doing! if `w1` and `w2` are individual words, you're calculating the cosine similarity between the words themselves, which is probably not what you want. Instead, you want the cosine similarities between `lst1` and `lst2` as a table you can index into, so you can do the whole computation once and then look up the results.

Comment: i.e., `similarity_table = cosine_similarity(lst1, lst2)`, then index into `similarity_table` for whatever you need. Can you give us everything we need to be able to run and test your code? Otherwise suggesting optimizations is basically impossible as we can't compare the suggestions to the existing code.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury Thanks, I have updated my code.

Comment: The problem with applying this approach on 2 lists instead of strings is that I get an `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'` error.